# How to request multilpe API at inital state and show data in UI using bloc?

Tags: flutter, state, flutter-dependencies, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have one question if I have two APIs, and the second API depends on the first, mean first need to fetch data from the first API then take the ID from it need to request 2nd API and show both APIs Data on UI how to manage it with bloc?